# 'SystimaDieythynsis' & 'Mihani' does not name a type

Tags: c++

The title explains the question, why won't it compile?

```
class Vehicle {


private:

    char* idioktitis,arKykloforias;
    int etosKat;
    SystimaDieythynsis sysdief;
    Mihani eng;

};

class Mihani {

private:

    int kyvismos,ippodynami;
public:

    void leitourgia();
    void kinisi();
    void svysimo();
};

void SystimaDieythynsis::vazeiEmpros(){

    cout << "Bazei Empros";
}

void SystimaDieythynsis::svynei(){

    cout << "Svynei";
}

void SystimaDieythynsis::striveiAristera(){

    cout << "Strivei Aristera";
}

void SystimaDieythynsis::striveiDexia(){

    cout << "Strivei Dexia";
}

void Mihani::leitourgia(){

    cout << "Leitourgia Mhxanhs";

}

void Mihani::kinisi(){

    cout << "Kinhsh Mhxanhs";

}

void Mihani::svysimo(){

    cout << "Svhsimo Mhxanhs";

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

   system("PAUSE");

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Please ask your question. I see code, but no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a class definition for `SystimaDieythynsis` and place it and the class definition for `Mihani` before the class definition for `Vehicle`.  Like so:

```
class Mihani { 
    // ...
};

class SystimaDieythynsis {
    // ...
};

class Vehicle {
    // ...
};

// insert function definitions here
```

Comment: Because Vehicle is a class name, not an array, or any other class with operator[]. Check this small [example](http://ideone.com/KzbKeg).

Comment: @User96 Simple for who? :) It really depends. But You should know, that this site is to help with programming problems, no to solve Your homework exercises. Please, write as much as You can by Yourself, and when You'll face some unknown problems, find answer for similar question or write Your own question. Cheers.